# Como crear automáticamente carpetas con timestamp y mover archivos (excepto carpetas) a la carpeta recién creada - Python

Tags: python, archivo

Se que se tiene que añadir  `import shutil` , pero no se como hacerlo.
Lo que hace mi código es que cada vez que entre uno o varios archivos, estos se impriman en el output.

```
import os
import time   
from os.path import isfile, join

path_to_watch = "C:/test"    
before = [f for i, f in enumerate(os.listdir("C:/test"))]

def showFilesData(files):       
    for i, j in enumerate(files):            
        if isfile(join("C:/test", j)):                
            file = open(join("C:/test", j))               
            print("Name:%s\n%s\n" % (j, file.read()))

showFilesData(before)

while 1:       
    time.sleep(5)        
    after = [f for i, f in enumerate(os.listdir ("C:/test"))]        
    added = [f for f in after if not f in before]        
    showFilesData(added)        
    before = after
```

Pero lo que quiero agregar es que se cree una carpeta en el directorio `C:/Test` que tenga como nombre la fecha y hora actual (`año-mes-dia-hora-minuto-segundo ---->  "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"`) y que los archivos que fueron impresos en el output sean movidos a la carpeta que fue recién creada.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que buscas lo puedes conseguir de forma simple mediante:

- [`datetime.datetime.now().strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now): Permite obtener la fecha y hora actuales y obtener una cadena con el formato requerido.
- [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs): Permite crear una ruta de directorios nuevos.
- [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move): Permite mover un archivo a otro directorio ya existente. Se puede renombrar el archivo a la vez que es movido.

Una función para hacer lo que quieres podría ser:

```
import datetime
import os
import shutil


def move_added(files, dest):
    if not files:
        return

    new_dir = os.path.join(dest, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"))
    if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
        os.makedirs(new_dir)

    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(dest, file)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            shutil.move(path, new_dir)
```

Solo hay que llamar a la función en tu ciclo `while`:

```
move_added(files, path_to_watch)
```